# Overwrite specific columns after modification pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file where i did some modifications in two columns. My question is the following: How can I print my csv file with the updated columns? My code is the following :

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = pd.read_csv("testdataset.csv")


data = data.join(pd.get_dummies(data["ship_from"]))
data = data.drop("ship_from", axis=1)


data['market_name'] = data['market_name'].map(lambda x: str(x)[39:-1])

data = data.join(pd.get_dummies(data["market_name"]))
data = data.drop("market_name", axis=1)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file with [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
data.to_csv('your_file.csv')
```

However, you can view it without writing with

```
print(data.to_csv())
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. For some reason, I was looking for a more complicated answer and didnt cross my mind. Thank you!